# What are the reasons for 'Unknown Pipeline node step' for some executors on a Jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Jenkins Version:**
CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.289.2.3-rolling

No Jobs Running

**Agent:**
Linux7-a-7

1   Idle
2   Idle
3   Idle
4   Unknown Pipeline node step
5   Unknown Pipeline node step

Linux7-a-8

1   Idle
2   Idle
3   Unknown Pipeline node step
4   Idle
5   Unknown Pipeline node step