# "Unkown Pipeline node step" on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nodes, pipeline

Lately one of our Jenkins nodes has developed an issue with its executors. From a total of 8, three of them are unavailable (meaning, neither "idle" nor "busy") showing that "Unknown Pipeline node step" status message.

A similar thread was opened on the same topic in [What are the reasons for 'Unknown Pipeline node step' for some executors on a Jenkins agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605432/what-are-the-reasons-for-unknown-pipeline-node-step-for-some-executors-on-a-je), but I think nobody has found a root or solution yet or simply this is just a very unfrequent issue.

I've checked the node under Jenkins monitoring to see if any thread could be killed (but to no avail) and recently tried to delete the node and recreate it with the same name in the hope this would reset the state of all its executors.

Comment: we just had the issue, restarting Jenkins fixed it